# Cron tab Not working in ec2-ubuntu server

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, cron

I am trying to run cron tab on particular time as I have edited `crontab -e` file and set as `36 07 * * * ubuntu /usr/bin/python uploadFileOnS3.py` But it's not working and I have also set another cron tab as `34 07 * * * pg_dump --no-owner revisedportals > /home/ubuntu/Backups/`date +\%Y\%m\%d`_mybackup` this is working fine.
My file permission is `-rwxrwxr-x 1 ubuntu ubuntu 801 Jun 20 07:21 uploadFileOnS3.py`. 
what could be the problem?

Comment: Try this? `36 07 * * * /usr/bin/python uploadFileOnS3.py`, remove the user ubuntu which is incorrect.

Comment: trying to do same lets see.

Comment: @ajreal no success

Comment: What is the error being return?

Comment: @ajreal How should I check error log?

Comment: You realize that 36 07 means the cronjob will execute on 7.36am? You can try to run /usr/bin/python uploadFileOnS3.py, is the file path correct? Usually, you should use the absolute path.

Comment: @ajreal, Yes I have tried using absolute path too but still no success. Yes I want to do it on same time  7.36am.

Comment: If I run file without cron tab it's working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the logs from

```
grep CRON /var/log/syslog
```

I guess this link would be helpful for you
[https://askubuntu.com/questions/56683/where-is-the-cron-crontab-log][1]

Comment: you should give the complete path for uploadFileOnS3.py

Comment: what was in the  syslogs . Does running in the shell working fine ?

Comment: This is the output `Jun 20 11:09:01 ip-172-31-29-3 CRON[9735]: (ubuntu) CMD (/usr/bin/python /home/ubuntu/Backups/uploadFileOnS3.py)
Jun 20 11:09:02 ip-172-31-29-3 cron[1068]: sendmail: fatal: open /etc/postfix/main.cf: No such file or directory
Jun 20 11:09:02 ip-172-31-29-3 postfix/sendmail[9739]: fatal: open /etc/postfix/main.cf: No such file or directory
Jun 20 11:09:02 ip-172-31-29-3 CRON[9734]: (ubuntu) MAIL (mailed 204 bytes of output but got status 0x004b from MTA#012)
`

Comment: manage the ouput(stderr and stdout) of uploadFileOnS3.py to a output file .
like add command /usr/bin/python /home/ubuntu/Backups/uploadFileOnS3.py > /tmp/s3Backup.log

Comment: Error log solved my problem , Thanks for the direction !!